# First neural net - weights don't converge

Tags: neural-network, gam, convergence

i just wrote my first implementation of a neural network for the game tic-tac-toe.

I have 9 input neurons (1,0,-1 for the state), and 1 output neuron (from -1 to 1 - that's the value of the state).

I use a simple reinforcement algorithm:
 The winning state gets the value +1, the previous state gets 1-1*scale, the next state 1-2*scale and so on.
 The losing state gets the value -1, the previous state gets -1+1*scale, the next state -1+2*scale and so on. (optional so far)

I feed this values into the network to get an error function to work with.
In the next iteration, i take all possible states and feed them into the network. Then i select the state with the highest value.

Now the problem is: If i only use the rewards for winning, the algorithm works
just fine, the output values converge to the values calculated by the reward-formula. I get winning rates around 85% against a random player.
If i use rewards for winning *and* (negative) rewards for losing, the algorithm does not converge at all and tends to output only positive, or only negative values (around +1 or around -1).

Does anybody know what could be the reason behind this? I use the tanh(x) output function for my neurons.

Thanks and best wishes,

beinando

Comment: Hey there i think i know why... if a state is "neutral" like 2 steps before winning and losing state, it can either be +0.6 and -0.6, for example. I dont recalculate the value from the state in the state_database, but just replace it. I will try it out with the new way, soon.

Comment: update: this fix does not work unfortunately... i still got either +1 or -1 as outputs from the neural net.. also, i tried to set the goal values to 0 (lose) and 2(win) instead of -1,1 to fix possible complications with the sign...